# Como Fazer Insert MYSQL caso seja Upload ou URL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ola, gostaria de saber como fazer um insert mysql, porem do modo que fiz apenas ultilizo o javascript apenas para alterar o imput URL para o File, ou seja, estou tentando trabalhar no mesmo imput name, porem tenho duvida do que fazer no insert caso a pessoa nao queira ultilizar o upload e apenas inserir a url, ou caso contrario, abaixo esta o codigo, pode ser que nao esteja correto porem se alguem puder me ajudar, desde ja agradeço.

```js
$("#pre").click(function() {
        var icon = $(this).find("i");
        $("#jc_preview").fadeOut("fast");
        if (icon.hasClass("fa-cloud-upload")) {
            $(this).fadeOut("fast", function() {
                icon.removeClass("fa-cloud-upload").addClass("fa-chain");
                $("#jc_preview").prop("type", "file").fadeIn("fast");
                $(this).fadeIn("fast");
            });
        } else {
            $(this).fadeOut("fast", function() {
                icon.removeClass("fa-chain").addClass("fa-cloud-upload");
                $("#jc_preview").prop("type", "url").fadeIn("fast");
                $(this).fadeIn("fast");
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
   
       $subtitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subtitle']);
       $preview  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['preview']);
       $preview  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES["preview"]["tmp_name"];);
       $title    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['title']);
       $date     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
   
       $new_name = uniqid(); // Novo nome aleatório do arquivo
       $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["preview"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Pega extensão de arquivo e converte em caracteres minúsculos.
       $folder = "imagens";
       move_uploaded_file($preview, $folder."/".$new_name.".".$extension);
   
       $subtitle = strlen($subtitle) > 0 ? "'$subtitle'" : "NULL";
       $preview  = strlen($preview) > 0 ? "'$preview'" : "NULL";
   
       $vsl = "INSERT INTO `files` (`id`, `subtitle`, `preview`, `title`, `date`)VALUES(NULL, $subtitle, $preview, '$title', '$date')";
       $rsl = mysqli_query($conn, $vsl);
   
       header("Location: ../admin/add.php");
       exit();
   
   }
   ?>
<form action="../actions/create_player.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label>Title: <i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Insert Title For This Player"></i></label>
   <input name="title" class="form-control" type="text" required="required">
   <label for="preview" class="control-label">Custom Preview:</label> <i class="fa fa-info-circle text-muted" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Insert Custom Preview URL For This Video"></i><span class="pull-right"><span class="label label-info cp" id="pre"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i></span></span>
   <input type="url" class="form-control" id="jc_preview" name="preview" placeholder="Insert Custom Preview URL">
   <br>
   <label>Subtitle: <i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Subtitle For Player"></i></label>
   <input name="subtitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Subtitles in VTT or Srt Formats" type="url">
   <button type="submit" name="create" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Publish</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Voce quer dizer upoad de arquivo em seu servidor por uma url? Eu tenho um arquivo php, que faz copia entre servidores distintos. Funciona como um download utilizando url. basta voce criar um campo text o usuario coloca a url.clica em upload(para fim de exemplo ) o arquivo ja estara disponibilizado em sua hospedagem

Comment: Porem se voce quer que o usuario tenha acesso a esse arquivo indico armazenar o nome deles em banco de dados. Depois quando for fazer a exibicao voce pega apenas o texto do nome. Adaptando claro.

Comment: e quase isso, quero ultilizar um type "post" e um "File", o Post e para armazenar qualquer url de Imagem adicionado no input POST  no banco, ou ele tem a opção de fazer o upload de qualquer arquivo e salvar, porem nao estou sabendo como ultilizar os 2 requisitos para adicionar ao banco de dados caso seja upload ou apenas o post

Comment: Na verdade tanto faz um como o outro. A diferenca eh que o campo input copia do computador. E o esquema que eu to falando copia pela url. Voce vai continuar usando o mesmo codigo. Apenas acrecentar o meu. E adicionar uma exclusao do arquivo apos insert.

Comment: Mais tarde te mando o esquema se ninguem tiver respondido.

Comment: ok, Obrigado pela colaboração!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aqui vai um esquema para para copia de arquivos entre servidores

```
<?php
$url_download = $_POST['campourl'];
$salvar_em = 'arquivo.jpj';
//inciando download
copy($url_download, $salvar_em);
//download finalizado
//aqui você faz as adaptações nessesarias

//final do arquivo - apagando o arquivo criado.
unlink($salvar_em);
?>
```

Comment: conseguiu adaptar?